# Postgres: limit length of returned string but needs to end on a full word

Tags: string, postgresql

With Postgres I am trying to truncate a string before returning it so that I can display it in a partial results list client-side. The key is that it needs to end on a full word. I've gotten as far as:
`SELECT comments, substr(comments, 1, 80) AS "trunc" FROM book;` Would the next step be to do a substring of the substring with RegEx (perhaps trying to make sure the string ends on a space)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`substring(string from pattern)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html). Example for 12 characters:

```
with the_data(comments) as (
    values
        ('follow me'::text),
        ('abcdef ghijkl'),
        ('abcd efgh ijkl'),
        ('abc def ghi jkl'),
        ('ab cd ef gh ij kl')
    )

select substring(left(comments || ' ', 12) from '.*\s')
from the_data;

  substring   
--------------
 follow me 
 abcdef 
 abcd efgh 
 abc def ghi 
 ab cd ef gh 
(5 rows)
```

Comment: If you add this example `('follow me'::text)` - it cuts off 'me', but my interpretation of OPs question would be that it should return 'follow me' (in this example).

Comment: If you simply added a single space following the value in `comments` it seems that may resolve it: `select substring(left(comments || ' ', 12) from '.*\s')
from the_data;`

Comment: Actually the word it ends on doesn't matter as long as it's a full word.

Comment: Yea - this is a nice answer. +1

Comment: Thanks very much klin and @Nicarus.